# AngularJS/Rails - Updating View on new API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm making a single page app with Angular using Rails as a backend API that loads a bunch of videos when first loading the page (initial API call - Youtube). I want to be able to make a search feature on the page, that when clicked, will initialize another API call, and update the view with new videos based on the search. I can get the initial load to work with the following code:

Controller:

```
App.controller('VideoCtrl', ['$scope', 'Video', ($scope, Video) ->
  $scope.videos = Video.query
  ])
```

Service:

```
App.factory('Video', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
  return $resource('api/videos', {}, {
   query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
   });
  }
 ]);
```

When I make the initial API call using Rails, the JSON data gets sent to the 'api/videos' URL, and then the Service pulls in the data into my VideoCtrl controller and then gets sent to the View. I would like to do something similar when making the new search API call, and I've set it up to the point where, I can retrieve the new JSON data from the new API call and display it in an updated 'api/vidoes' URL (something like 'api/videosutf8=✓&q%5Bteam%5D=**NEWOBJECT**&commit=Search') but am having trouble having it display in the view.

Do I need to make another Service, and inject that into my existing controller (if so, then would I make $scope.videos dependent on which Service to use?), or do I make a new controller (but then I would have to modify the view to use a certain controller based on if the user searched or not?)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, where you use the built in $promise in $resource in order to make the call asynchronous and then set the view value when the call comes back.

```
$scope.videosSearch = Video.query();
$scope.videos = null;

$scope.videosSearch.$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.videos = result;
});
```

Comment: hm not sure if I'm getting you right, but tried implementing this and doesn't seem to change anything